# Post thumbnail images are displaying out of parent div

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am displaying the recent post on the home page and I am using the below code. Now the issue is, I am getting all the post images out of the parent div and content are displaying properly. I am getting the output like

**Example of current output**

```
<div class="entry-content">
<img>
<img>
<img>
<div class="cp-seeWrapper">
<div class="row"><div class="col">
//my content are displaying here which is correct
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Images are displaying in the wrong place. It should be displayed after my class `cp-seeSinglePostWrapper`.

Whatever I am adding the logic that all are displaying above parent div.

**Full code here**

```
 function recentPost_on_home(){
$data='<div class="cp-seeWrapper"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="row">';
            $args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'nopaging' => true);
            // set up new query
            $tyler_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            // loop through found posts
            if ($tyler_query->have_posts()) {
                while ( $tyler_query->have_posts() ) {
          $tyler_query->the_post();
          $categories = get_the_category();
          if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
          $cat_list= esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
            }
          $data.= '<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="cp-shadow cp-seeSinglePostWrapper">
          '.get_the_post_thumbnail().'<div class="bg-white single-post-box">
               <div class="d-flex cp-CategoryList">
               <div class="seeDate">'.get_the_date('F j, Y').'</div>'.$cat_list.'</div>
    <a href="'.esc_url( get_the_permalink() ).'" title="'.esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ).'" class="seePost_title">'.wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 10, '...').'</a>
      <p>'.wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 20, '...').'</p>
  </div>
              </div>
                        </div>';

        }
      }
  $data.='</div></div>';
  $data.='<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><div class="cp-social cp-shadow bg-white"><h3>Social</h3>';
            if (is_active_sidebar('footer-social')) :
                 dynamic_sidebar('footer-social');
                endif;
  $data.='</div></div></div></div>';
 return $data;    
}
add_shortcode( 'home_recent_post', 'recentPost_on_home' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_post_thumbnail()`

echos the result. You should use `get_the_post_thumbnail()`

Cheers!

Comment: Oh! Yes, It's working after using your answer...What about the_category()? I am getting the same issue in the category. I changed it from the_category() to get_the_category() but I am getting Array output.

Comment: If I add anything then that also displaying out of the parent div. Now I tried to display in col-4 and it's displayed above my parent div.

Comment: get_the_category() returns an array of WP_Terms https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/ . In order to display the first use get_the_category[0]->name. And also change the_permalink to esc_url( get_the_permalink() )

Comment: I tried get_the_category[0]->name and it's not displaying anything.

Comment: I updated the code in the question. Now I am getting the category. But If I use $categories[0]->name then I am getting only one categry name.. I have a single product with more then 1 category listed.

Comment: You will just have to loop through all the categories then like so : 
$categories = get_tge_category();
$names = '';
if ( $categories && is_array( $categories )) {
foreach ( $categories as $cat ) { $names .= $cat->name . ' '; }

Now $names would hold all the category names separated with a space ' '.

Comment: oh!..correct.. Yes, I a getting the correct. Spelling mistake get_tge_category and } missing in your last comment.

Comment: I have one last doubt. In case I have to show only 2 categories then what code I have to use it? Please help me

Comment: You should add a counter var before the foreach or change the foreach to for. Example $counter = 0; foreach( $categories as $cat ) { if ( $counter > 1 ) break; /*Same Stuff as Before Here */ $counter++; }